# Trouble installing with d3-context-menu with bower using VS code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to install the d3-context-menu for my vue js and d3.js web app. For reference here is the github [here](https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu/blob/master/README.md) I don't have bower installed so I installed it using

```
npm install -g bower
```

Then I ran the command

```
bower install d3-context-menu
```

However I get the error message

```
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.      
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using "--allow-root" option
```

I looked this up online and I cannot find a fix. Would this be because of me using d3v6 or that the context menu github is outdated?

Or is their a better alternative to create a context menu using d3.js?

I am very new to this so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this package in two other ways.

Some examples are described in the README file, [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hAx36JQhb0RsvVn7TomS?p=info&preview) and [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bDBe0xGX1mCLzqYGOqOS?p=info&preview), where the author uses the package including the script tag directly in HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="d3-context-menu.css" />
<script src="d3-context-menu.js"></script>
```

A second way is to install the package using npm. This package is published in the npm registry: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-context-menu.

So, theoretically, all you need is:

```
npm i d3-context-menu
```

I haven't tested the second way, but the canonical form can be tested directly in the online environment where the examples are, the Plunker platform and it works.